# Weblogic Spring Dependency Injection from flat-files on the file-system

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, weblogic

I have an application deployed into Oracle Weblogic 10.3.  In my .ear files, I use spring injection from xml files in the ear files. I would like to also perform dependency injection from xml files placed on the server file-system.  We do something similar to this in Karaf, where we place our configuration files for bundles in the conf directory in the server itself. Is there a similar way to do this in weblogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask **spring to read properties from file systems** as below;

```
<!-- Reads application properties and uses them in the application context -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:D:\somefolder\application.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:com/foo/sp.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Wow, what an elegant solution!  Can the value in the "file" url be relative? Also, my development is done on Windows, but the app actually is deployed to a linux variant. Is there any way to make this work in a cross platform manner sort of like how commons-io's fileUtils package converts the path to the type needed by the OS the system is on?

Comment: I mean, relative to the server location. If the development server is c:\blah